# What happens during conduction of heat in solids?

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I have studied that in conduction heat just gets transfered between the layer of a solid. But in which form?

Does that mean electron exite due to given heat and then come back and the released energy gets absorbed by other atom and then continued till the end?

Comment: This appears to be an exact duplicate of a question posted by another person over at Chemistry SE and they posted earlier. Hence my downvote. Linked question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/170507/79678.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heat transfer in solids happens this way:

remember that what we call heat is the random vibrations of the particles (atoms or molecules) that make up the hot object, and the more violent the vibrations are, the "hotter" we say the object is.

We make those vibrations more violent by adding kinetic energy to the vibrating objects so they are moving faster. Now they are hotter. but since in a solid all the atoms are connected together with atomic bonds, when one particle starts vibrating faster than its neighbors, it quickly transfers that kinetic energy to the surrounding particles and they begin vibrating more violently too. in this manner, heat is *conducted* through the solid.

In metals, heat is also conducted by the movement of the (delocalized) electrons that form the *metallic bonds* holding the metal atoms together. This is one reason that metals are better conductors of heat than nonmetals.